# http request with php curl and basic auth

Tags: php, rest, http, authentication, curl

I am using php curl to call an external api that requires basic auth. I am able to call it in postman and I am able to receive a response. However, it seems to timeout otherwise on my own. Here is how I am calling it in php.

```
$form_details_url = "xxxx"; //url
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";

echo "request " . $form_details_url . PHP_EOL;

$ch = curl_init();

if(!$ch){
  die("could not initiate curl handle");
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $form_details_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $result = json_decode($response, true);
  print_r($result);
}

die();
```

This code snippet is from postman which does give me a response.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "xxxxxxxx",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic ZGl0LWNmaS1wZHgtcmVtb3RlOmRpdC1jZmktcGR4LXJlbXNsZWVw",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Postman-Token: xxxxxxx",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated. My guess is I am approaching the problem wrong regarding auth within php curl request. Thanks kindly.

Comment: "it seems to timeout otherwise on my own" <- what do you mean exactly? You should receive some kind of error/response (even if there is a timeout), can you post it?

Comment: this is the respose I am receiving 
```
* Trying xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to xxxx port 80 failed: Connection timed out
*   Trying xxx ...
* TCP_NODELAY set
`